Help me find a manhwa/manhua about a dragon princess and her stepfather
I was watching a YouTube video where the main character (MC) finds a female dragon in a cave.
Before she dies, she gives the MC her egg. Later, the story unfolds: he encounters other humanoid races like Asuras and the dragon race. He discovers that the female dragon he met was a princess of the Dragon Kingdom and heir to the throne.
Now, her daughter is the rightful heir. He leaves her (the princess) with her grandfather, the King of the Dragon Kingdom, who appears to be in human form.
Interestingly, her granddaughter, who was initially in dragon form, can now transform into a human. The MC departs because he has other obligations.
I had added this video to a YouTube playlist, but it seems to be deleted or hidden, and I can't find it anymore.
Can anyone identify this manhwa/manhua? Based on the art style, I believe it's more likely a manhwa.

"I had added this video to a YouTube playlist, but it seems to be deleted or hidden, and I can't find it anymore." See the solution suggested at: Web Apps SE- Is there a way to search only liked videos in my YouTube account? You may be able to find the video.

To be fair this match 100% plot of The Beginning After The End. But the time different between chapter is too huge (about + 100c)

@someoneuseless If it's from a youtube compilation, the video creator could have just spliced together random scenes from all over the series. If tbate has a dying dragon entrust the protagonist with an egg, then it seems like a decent match, regardless of when the events happen.

That why I comment both info about race and meeting with grandfather OP mention is it way too scarce. It skip about 4-5 arc and remove a lot of easter egg led to the info.

Is it The Beginning After the End?
Quoting from Wikipedia:

In the realm of Etharia, King Grey was a great ruler but with a sense of guilt for his past mistakes. When he dies of poisoning, he was reincarnated in the realm of Dicathen as Arthur Leywin. With a second chance of living, Grey/Arthur explores his new home, with family and friends, but he then discovers there is a great danger hidden, and that he was not the only one who reincarnated.

